# How to get list of commits that were not push to master GitPython

Tags: python, gitpython

I am using GitPython,

I am trying to somehow see if all my local commits where push to the remote server. I can see differences between my current local state and master doing this :

```
import git
t = repo.heads['master'].commit.tree
repo.git.diff(t)
```

but I can't figure out how to check if commits where pushed or not

Comment: Not related to git python, but usually you can do this using `git log origin/master..master`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @mvp

you can use `repo.git.log('origin/master..master')`

Comment: @OliverSpryn: it does provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
from git import *

repo = Repo("YOUR_GIT_REPO")
unpushed_commits = list(repo.iter_commits('origin/master..master'))

first_commit = unpushed_commits[0]
print(first_commit.author)
```